# Hive 1.2.1. How to increase google.protobuf limits?

Tags: hadoop, hive, protocol-buffers

I have following error when trying to read some data from Hive:

> Bad status for request TFetchResultsReq(fetchType=0,
>   operationHandle=TOperationHandle(hasResultSet=True,
>   modifiedRowCount=None, operationType=0,
>   operationId=THandleIdentifier(secret='\x02\xa83\xf3\xd8xB\x17\xbf\x96\x92\x80A\xbf\x89\x04',
>   guid='\x03*\x85g\x11CE\xcd\xb2<\x8c\xbc\xacC\xcd"')), orientation=4,
>   maxRows=100): TFetchResultsResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=0,
>   errorMessage='java.io.IOException:
>   com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message
>   was too large. May be malicious. Use CodedInputStream.setSizeLimit()
>   to increase the size limit.',

Google says that there is no way to increase default limit via configs, but only via rebuilding Hive. Is it true? And how to check my current limits?

Also I've found issue in Hive's JIRA where patch for increasing default buffer limit from 64MB to 1GB has been added. Seems that patch would be in future releases, but I'm not sure.

Thanks.